# Passwordless sign-in with Firebase, open link from a PC

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I've just set up Firebase's Passwordless sign-in in my iOS app and everything works great! The thing is, if I open the verification link from a PC, it will open a website displaying an error. (see image below)

Is it normal behavior? Is it possible to open the app's AppStore link, as I selected this option when I set up the `Dynamic Links`?

[image]

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem – have you found a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Did you redirect the URL whitelisted on your firebase project's credentials section on GCP oAuth consent ?

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Comment: No, I didn't! Is there a guide?